# Suppressing First Part of Output in Makefile

Tags: makefile

```
DEPRECATED_CHECK := $(shell grep "test454" tex/*.tex)

ifneq ($(DEPRECATED_CHECK), )
$(warning \test454 is deprecated. Use \test2 instead)
endif
```

When I run this I get:

```
../common/Makefile.include:133: \test454 is deprecated. Use \test2 instead
```

That's fine, but I'd quite like to have only:

```
\test454 is deprecated. Use \test2 instead
```

Is this possible? Some sort of awk function? I think I need something with:

```
@echo \text454 is deprecated ...
```

But I don't know how to get this working with the basic purpose of my MWE, as it keeps complaining about missing separators.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$(info ...)` instead of `$(warning ...)`.  `info` doesn't prepend the file and line number.

just an aside -- I usually try to do those sort of checks as part of a sanity rule, and make everything depend on that rule instead of doing it at the top level.  It gives you more flexibility that way.  For example, if you didn't want to run the check when building clean, it becomes simple, or if you wanted to fail the build if a check failed, it becomes simple as well.

---

**EDIT** *(adding more detail on aside)*

Instead of doing an `ifneq` at the top level of make, you could add a target as so:

```
sanity_check: 
   @ ! grep -q "test454" tex/*.txt || echo "test454 is depricated"

.PHONY: sanity check
```

The add dependencies of your main targets to sanity check:

```
all maintarg1 maintarg2: sanity_check
```

This way the sanity check will be run before any of your main targets, and will output as desired.   This is in my opinion, a cleaner way of doing the test.   This way the test is only run if you are building any of your targets, and will not be run, if for example you are making `clean`, or if your makefile was included by a parent makefile, or in a bunch of other corner cases that might pop up in the future.

Just a quick note on the recipe syntax: the `@` is a make directive that tells make not to echo the command as it's run.  The `!` is bash syntax to inverse the return of grep (so `! grep` returns false if the text is found, thereby causing the `||` part of the statement to be evaluated.).   The `.PHONY: sanity_check` tells make to run the rule, even if a file called `sanity_check` already exists

Comment: Could you elaborate on your aside by any chance? I'm not sure if I follow: I'm not a programmer and I'm using this for LaTeX (I'm a tech writer). My knowledge of Bash isn't fantastic.